# Return results based on datetime parameter

Tags: sql

I have a database table called `Fees`. In that table, I have `FeeTypeEnum`, `EffectiveDate`, and `Amount` columns.

Example of Table:

```
ID   FeeTypeEnum   EffectiveDate   Amount
-----------------------------------------
1    1             1/1/2013        13.00
2    1             10/1/2013       98.36
3    2             4/1/2013        53.00
4    2             6/1/2013        51.00
5    3             7/1/2013        53.00
6    1             12/1/2012       12.00
```

How would I return only the results that would considered to be active based on the a `datetime` parameter date. For example: If today was **5/1/2013**, only the following would be returned:

```
ID   FeeTypeEnum   EffectiveDate   Amount
-----------------------------------------
1    1             1/1/2013        13.00
3    2             4/1/2013        53.00
```

I was thinking that I could just group them by `FileTypeEnum` and then remove the ones that are before the current date. Would that work?

### Edit

Basically, I'm trying to return all the results where the `EffectiveDate` is **BEFORE** the `datetime` parameter and **NOT** the results where the `EffectiveDate` is **AFTER** the parameter.

### Edit 2

When using the following query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Fees]
  WHERE [EffectiveDate] <= GETDATE()
  ORDER BY [FeeEnum]
```

It also returns results for records that are no longer considered active. How would I select only 1 from each `[FeeEnum]` group?

Comment: I dont see the relationship between 1/1/2012 and the dates in the table.

Comment: Sorry, updated my post. Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: So just perform a query asking for records with a date field that is before (less than) a specific date (a literal). You automatically exclude the ones after. This seems so obvious that I assume your real question is something more. You are using a date or date-time data type for that EffectiveDate column?

Comment: Yes, that query also returns records that are no longer considered active.

Answer (score 0):

New at this but I belive you want to bring back anything < systdate.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE EffectiveDate<SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Fees
WHERE EffectiveDate <= @asOfDate
```

How you are *calling* the SQL (e.g. a stored procedure or directly form an application) will determine how to set the `@asOfDate` parameter.

Comment: I'm calling it via a stored procedure. I know how to declare the variable, just not sure how to create the `WHERE` clause.